# How send image and array with text to Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, xcode, operating-system, watchkit, watchos-2

After start watch-app I do request session to iPhone, but when I try return Image as NSData i get

```
Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7011 "Message reply failed." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x78e9b8d0 {Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7009 "Payload is too large." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Send smaller payloads., NSLocalizedDescription=Payload is too large.}},
```

For communicate I use

```
session.sendMessage(...)
```

And how I should pass image and text from iPhone to Watch?

Comment: You can see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113823/how-to-transfer-a-uiimage-using-watch-connectivity in this question

Comment: Have you tried scaling the high-resolution image to fit the smaller watch screen, *before* transferring it as data? That would likely help the image data to not exceed [the payload limits](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35076706/4151918), as well as be more energy-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code:

**JPEG Image**

```
if WCSession.isSupported(){
    WCSession.defaultSession().activateSession()
    WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessageData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "imageName.jpeg")!)!, replyHandler: {(_) -> Void in
    }) {(error) -> Void in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**PNG Image**

```
if WCSession.isSupported(){
    WCSession.defaultSession().activateSession()
    WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessageData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "imageName.png")!)!, replyHandler: {(_) -> Void in
    }) {(error) -> Void in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code for the iPhone to send or Apple Watch?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 Version:

```
WCSession.default.activate()
WCSession.default.sendMessageData(UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "imageName.png")!)!, replyHandler: {(_) -> Void in
                }) {(error) -> Void in
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
```