# Send dictionary data to apple watch from ios applicaton

Tags: ios, swift, wcsession

In my app, I have this page named "TicketDetailViewController" in which i have 3 labels and an imageView in which data is displayed from previous page. Now what i want is when i click on my "sendtowatch" button, i want to send the displayed data i.e 3 labels and an imageView to my apple watch where there also i have taken 3 labels and an imageView in its storyboard. The problem is i am using FMDB database for storing and retrieving data. Now on my button click from my IOS app, the displayed data will be saved in Database and at the same time i also needs to retrieve it so that the watch can receive the latest data that i have stored in database. I have tried the solution but no luck.

here is my screenshot for my running app page below
 [screenshot for my running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVo9j.png)

my source code from IOS side  is below:

```
 @IBAction func sendToWatch(sender: AnyObject) {


    let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if ticketDB.open()
    {

        let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (image, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(display_image.image!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

        let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

        if !result
        {

            print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

        } else
        {

            let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved to Database!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

            alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action:
                { (ACTION) -> Void in
                    let ticketInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
                    let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath as String)
                    if ticketDB.open()
                    {

                        let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET"

                        let result: FMResultSet? = ticketDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                        if let result = result
                        {
                            self.ticketDataArray = NSMutableArray()
                            while result.next()
                            {

                                ticketInfo["ticket_category"] = self.ticket_category.text
                                ticketInfo["ticket_type"] = self.ticket_type_name.text
                                ticketInfo["date"] = self.ticket_date.text
                                ticketInfo["time"] = self.ticket_time.text
                                ticketInfo["image"] = self.display_image.image
                                print("Data: \(ticketInfo)")

                            }
                            let dict = ["Watchdat":ticketInfo]

                            self.session.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: { (replayDic: [String:AnyObject]) -> Void in
                                print(replayDic["Watchdat"])
                                }, errorHandler: { (error:NSError) -> Void in
                                    print(error.description)
                            })

                        }else
                        {
                            print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                        }

                    ticketDB.close()

                    }


            }))

            self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(databasePath)

        }
    }
```

my source code from watch side is below

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

var session: WCSession!



@IBOutlet var watch_displayImage: WKInterfaceImage!
@IBOutlet var watch_ticket_category: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet var watch_ticketType: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet var watch_ticketTime: WKInterfaceLabel!
@IBOutlet var watch_ticketDate: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if WCSession.isSupported()
    {

        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()

    }


}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()


}


func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    print(message.values)

    var dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
    watch_ticket_category.setText(dict["Watchdat"]! as? String)
}
```

}

Comment: when i tap on send to watch, nothing appears in console and only data is saved and nothing else

Comment: is it something wrong in my code or not?. I am not getting it

Comment: Did you activate the session on your iOS app? And is the watch reachable when you send the message?

Comment: yes session is activated on both the sides..how do i do it reachable?

Comment: `self.session.isReachable`

Comment: where do i write it in my above code

Comment: You need to check if the watch is reachable right before you send the message to the watch

Comment: Debug your code for every step and identify the problem. Find out if you can fetch data from FMDB or if send message func does its job correctly.

Comment: nothing is happening?

Comment: fetched data is printed on console only if i run IOS app but when my run IOS+watch app together it shows nothing in console

Answer (score 1):

#### On the iOS side:

You spend the time constructing an array of tickets, but then don't do anything with that array. You passed a single ticket's dictionary, instead of passing an array of ticket dictionaries.

```
let ticketInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
...
self.ticketDataArray = NSMutableArray()
while result.next()
{
    ticketInfo.setObject(result.stringForColumn("image"), forKey: "image")
    ticketInfo.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_category"), forKey: "ticket_category")
    ticketInfo.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_type"), forKey: "ticket_type")
    ticketInfo.setObject(result.stringForColumn("date"), forKey: "date")
    ticketInfo.setObject(result.stringForColumn("time"), forKey: "time")
    self.ticketDataArray.addObject(ticketInfo)
}
let dict = ["Watchdat":ticketInfo]
```

You should either omit constructing the array, or pass the right value intended for that key.

#### On the watchOS side:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()
watch_ticket_category.setText(dict["Watchdat"]! as? String)
```

The dictionary you're checking is a new, empty dictionary you just created. However, the phone's data that the watch received was passed to `didReceiveMessage` in the `message` parameter. If you check *that* dictionary, you should find what you're expecting.

Note that the value for "Watchdat" key can't be conditionally cast to a String. You also need to correct that, depending on whether you meant that key's value to be a dictionary or an array.

If you meant for it to be a nested dictionary, as your code is written now, you'd have to set each label, like so:

```
watch_ticket_category.setText(message["Watchdat"]!["ticket_category"])
```

#### Regarding the image:

Your record's image column type is a string, but you expect to the watch to display an `WKInterfaceImage`. If you intended to pass an image to the watch, you'll also need to fix that code on the iOS side.

There are plenty of answers on SO explaining how to transfer an image to the watch. The two things you should keep in mind are:

- The size of the image. Don't waste time and battery life transferring a high-res image which will end  up being displayed on a smaller watch screen. Scale the image *before* transferring it.
- The max payload size that `sendMessage` supports, especially if you're intending to transfer an array of tickets (and images), instead of a single ticket.

Comment: i have changed my source a little bit..i am passing dictionary like the one written in code..Now how do i pass this to my watch app

Comment: I updated my answer, to point out that you were checking an empty dictionary on the watch side. Instead, check the `message` dictionary that was passed to you. You'll also have to convert the phone's image to data *before* sending, or the `sendMessage` will fail with an error. Last point is that you've filled in `ticketInfo` *n* times inside the `results` loop, with the same details. Why are you doing that inside a loop? It's still not clear why `sendToWatch` even needs to construct some results array, since the array doesn't appear to have anything to do with "sending."

Comment: i am using FMDB database in which i have 5 columns named as image,ticket_category,ticket_type,date,time. So how can i fetch data and how can i convert my image to NSDATA?

Comment: Here is an existing question [explaining how to convert an image before sending it to the watch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113823/how-to-transfer-a-uiimage-using-watch-connectivity). If you have an unrelated question about how to fetch data from FMDB, you should ask a separate question.